# Odd Vanishing Visual Glitch (Both in Viewport and Render)

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, blend-files

I was prepping a render for a customer which involved this Mass Effect scene. But recently I updated my graphics drivers and PC and now even when I redownload the scene I still have an odd glitch.

When I look around in the viewport, random walls, and floors vanish from sight as if I am clipping into them but I have fiddled with clipping settings multiple times but to no avail. The missing walls and floors also do not appear in the final render as if they have been deleted. It is such a strange problem and I cannot figure out if it's something wrong with my PC or Blender, I don't think it is the scene as it used to work perfectly fine.

The most specific detail is more my view or the camera is what causes different objects of the scene to either vanish or come back into view.

Here is the scene if you are willing to test it out to see if you get the same issue: https://open3dlab.com/project/33781/

I really appreciate any ideas or help!

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Also be sure to break your wall of text into paragraphs so it isn't so hard to read

Comment: I've used the walk navigation to check the room and there were no missing/disappearing walls. A test render looked ok.